# Where does table get created when no filegroup is specified?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have 2 file groups. And 5 data files. Each filegroup has 2 data files. And 1 additional data file without any file group.

When I create a table specifying the file group and add records to this table, then data is proportionally filled amongst all data files in that file group.

I want to ask where does the table get created when no file group is specified?

Comment: I assume the downvotes are suggesting - "what happened when you tried?"

Answer (score 5):

To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

> If "default" is specified, or if ON is not specified at all, the table is stored on the default filegroup.

You can find the default filegroup or partition scheme with the following query

```sql
SELECT name
FROM sys.data_spaces ds  -- could also use 
WHERE ds.is_default = 1;
```